# How would I get these boxes to not only appear to the correct size but also evenly spaced within the main container?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeSWX.png)

I get this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYnCW.png)

What am I doing wrong in my code? Also, why does the button go all the way into the footer if I end that  before the footer  starts?

Thank you!

```css
.rs-container .rsboxsection {
    padding-top: 0;
}

.rs-container .rsboxsection .row {
    max-width: 64rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.rs-container .rsboxsection .row .layout .grid {
    margin-left: -12px;
    margin-right: -12px;
}

.rs-container .rsboxsection .row .layout .grid .grid-item .panel-interactive {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.rs-container .rsboxsection .row .layout .grid .grid-item .panel-interactive .title {
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.rs-container .rsboxsection .row .layout .grid .grid-item .panel-interactive .WSPanel a {
    display: block;
    border: 5px solid #0000FF;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    padding: 1.2em;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    min-height: 12.5em;
}

.rs-container .rsboxsection .row .layout .grid .grid-item .panel-interactive .WSPanel p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="rsboxsection">  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="layout">
      <div class="grid thirds">
        <!-- Westside Shuttle Button -->
        <div class="grid-item" style="height: 200px;">
          <div class="panel-interactive">
            <div class="WSPanel">
              <a href="routes/ws.html">
                <h3 class="title" style="font-weight:Bold">WS</h3>
                  <p>Services .... in some city.</p>
              </a>    
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).